# Exact division in python

Tags: integer, intervals, division

Im new to python and I wrote a program that scales values from the interval [-7000,18000] to the interval of [-1,1].

```
desired_upper_bound = 1.0
desired_lower_bound = -1.0
max_value = 18000.0
min_value = -7000.0
value = -7000.0
slope = (desired_upper_bound - desired_lower_bound) / (max_value - min_value)
print(slope)
intercept = desired_upper_bound - (slope * max_value)
print(intercept)
transformed_value = slope * value + intercept
print(transformed_value)
```

The exact result of 'transformed_value' should be -1, although console delivers: -1.0000000000000002. For the rest of my work it could  cause a lot of problems when the value is not in the interval, so Id like to know how to solve this issue.

I'd like to have the mathematical correct result of '1' calculated and displayed in the console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because floating point arithmetics are not exact. Quoting [floating-point arithmetic article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) on Wikipedia on that:

> floating-point arithmetic (FP) is arithmetic using formulaic
>   representation of real numbers as an **approximation** so as to support a
>   trade-off between range and precision.

Since it's only an approximation you'll encounter situations like that. If you want to force some numbers into a specific interval you can check if they do not exceed it and if they do, you could round them like this:

```
if transformed_value <= -1:
    transformed_value = round(transformed_value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. That is a very neat idea, will use this.